# Inheritance and Retrofit, unrecognized attributes

Tags: android, retrofit

I have two entities, Movie and Tv described as follows:

```
data class Movie(
val id: Int,
val title:String,
//other
):Serializable

data class Tv(
val id :Int,
val name:String,
//other
):Serializable
```

These are two entities representing objects obtainable through an API used obviously through Retrofit. As noted in the code, they share two attributes in common (*report only two but there are many more*) and other attributes characteristic of the single entity.

What I did was to create a parent class called Media:

```
open class Media(
val id:Int,
val title:String
):Serializable

class Movie(
id:Int,
title:String,
//other
):Media(
id,
title,
)

class Tv(
id:Int,
name:String,
//other
):Media(
id,
name,
)
```

And below are the two interfaces for communicating with the API:

#### MovieService

```
/**
     * This method generify the getPopular, getUpcoming & getTopRated
     */
    @GET("movie/{filter}")
    suspend fun getListOfSpecificMovies(
        @Path("filter") filter: String,
        @QueryMap queryMap: Map<String, String>
    ): GenericResponse<Movie>
```

#### TvService

```
 @GET("tv/{filter}")
    suspend fun getListOfSpecificTv(
        @Path("filter") filter: String,
        @QueryMap queryMap: Map<String, String>
    ): GenericResponse<TvShow>
```

The problem is that when I expose in the UI Tv and Movie, the movies possess the `title` value while instead the `name` value seems not to be tracked in Tv. Although they have different names, they represent the same concept of title. So how can I use entities that are part of an inheritance tree, within rest calls with retrofit?

Comment: What is TvShow data class?
Can you share that as well